# Error 9 subscript out of range when applying conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply some conditional formatting to my sheet, it errors out my code below

the line that errors out is

```
MyRange.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
```

do you think that i have the 2nd row  hidden, may impact the method?

```
Sub DraxCXLImport()

   Dim header As Integer
   Dim r As Integer
   
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   
   Worksheets("APM").Activate
   
   Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
   r = Selection.Rows.Count
   
   If r < 3 Then
       r = 3
   End If
   Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Activate
   
   'drag down formulas
   Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Range("A2:AA" & r).FillDown
   
   
   
  
   
   
   'add conditional formatting
   
   'Define Range
   Dim MyRange As Range
   
   
   Set MyRange = Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Range("S2:T" & r)

  'Delete Existing Conditional Formatting from Range
   MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete


       'Apply Conditional Formatting to Tier cancellation hours

   MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$S3<>$T3"
   MyRange.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
   
   With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       .Color = 65535
       .TintAndShade = 0
   End With
   
   Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
   
  
   
   
   
   
    'remove duplicates
   Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Range("A1:AA" & r).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), header:=xlYes
   
   
   
   Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Rows(2).Hidden = True
   
   Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Range("A1").Select
   
   
   Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   
   Err.Clear
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Resume Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using both `MyRange` and `Selection` in the line that's erroring - that's probably the cause of the problem.

However, `FormatConditions.Add()` *returns the added FormatCondition*, so you can simplify your code by using the return value directly in a `With` block:

```vb
Dim MyRange
'...
'...
Set MyRange = Worksheets("Cxl Policies").Range("S2:T" & r)

MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete

With MyRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$S3<>$T3")
   .SetFirstPriority
   .StopIfTrue = False
   With .Interior
       .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       .Color = 65535
       .TintAndShade = 0
   End With
End With
```